# Create a House using java

Tags: java, awt

Okay I was wondering three things so right now my house background is white how do I make it part blue and green for the grass bottom part. Also my line is going downward how do I make go up toward northeast to make the triangle for the ceiling of the house? Last thing what about adding a tree do I make a bunch of arcs to get the "bush curviness" of the tree?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;

public class House extends Canvas {
    public House() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics window) {
        window.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        window.drawRect(250, 300, 50, 125);
        window.fillRect(350, 300, 50, 135);
        window.setColor(Color.PINK);
        window.drawRect(200, 150, 350, 300);
        window.fillRect(200, 150, 350, 300);
        window.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        Polygon poly = new Polygon();
        poly.addPoint(100, 200);
        poly.addPoint(200, 400);
        poly.addPoint(300, 200);
        window.fillPolygon(poly);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all the open space? This makes your code very hard to read.

Comment: Start by having a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/).  You might also find [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) useful

Comment: Remember the coordinate system: (0,0) is upper left, with increasing y going downward on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

> how do I make it part blue and green for the grass bottom part

Don't use "magic" numbers, use absolute known values, like `getWidth` and `getHeight`, for example:

```
window.setColor(Color.BLUE);
window.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);

window.setColor(Color.GREEN);
window.fillRect(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);
```

> Also my line is going downward how do I make go up toward northeast to make the triangle for the ceiling of the house?

It's doing exactly what you told it to, remember, the top/left corner is `0x0`, meaning coordinates increase in size as the move right/down

```
Polygon poly = new Polygon();
poly.addPoint(100, 200);
poly.addPoint(200, 100);
poly.addPoint(300, 200);
```

> Last thing what about adding a tree do I make a bunch of arcs to get the "bush curviness" of the tree?

You could just use a series of over lapping ovals, using [`Graphics#fillOval`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillOval-int-int-int-int-) or [`Graphics#drawArc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawArc-int-int-int-int-int-int-)

I would strongly recommend that you have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for techniques and ideas when using `Graphics`.

I'd also encourage you to have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to understand how painting actually works in AWT/Swing